# im unable to validate a login of users ,since if im entering the wrong values my datareader is not getting executed y?

Tags: .net, sql, database, sql-server-2005, ado.net

//code

```
private void glassButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox1.Text == "" || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        Message m = new Message();
        m.ShowDialog();
    }

    else
    {
        try
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "Data source=BLACK-PEARL;Initial Catalog=LIFELINE ;User id =sa; password=143";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select LoginID,Password,Department from Login where LoginID=@loginID and Password=@Password and Department=@Department", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@loginID", textBox1.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", textBox2.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Department", comboBox1.Text));
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           if (dr.Read())
            {

                string Strname = dr[0].ToString();
               string StrPass = dr[1].ToString();
               string StrDept = dr[2].ToString();
               if(dr[2].ToString().Equals(comboBox1.Text)&&dr[0].ToString().Equals(textBox1.Text)&&dr[1].ToString().Equals(textBox2.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter correct details");
                }
            }
           dr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code without any explanation doesn't make for a good question. Tell us what you are trying to achieve, what you've tried to get it work etc.

Answer (score 2):

When there is no matching user it will return zero rows. 
You should check if it reader has any rows if not then it means that login details are wrong. Just include another else with this if statement.

```
if (dr.Read())
{
.........
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Please Enter correct details");
}
```

Comment: yes i changed it to AND from the && please tell me how to get my data reader object read the elements ???

Comment: thanks taz i got it whenever there is no matching row at the database .it wont return anything i mean the datareader doesnt have any rows to be executed ..so i included other else no its working fine ..thanks a lot dude

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `&&` with `AND` in your SQL:

```
SELECT LoginID,Password,Department
FROM Login
WHERE LoginID=@loginID
AND Password=@Password 
AND Department=@Department
```